# Pasar parametro de una Actividad a una Clase

Tags: android-studio, canvas, activity, class

tengo una ACTIVIDAD

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener, View.OnClickListener {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mAccelerometer;
    private Sensor mBrujula;
    private Button iniciar_crono;
    private TextView x_a;

    private DibujarBrujula brujula;

    //
    private InetAddress IPAddress;
    public float azimut;
    private int puertoServ = 5000;
    private DatagramSocket clientSocket;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        brujula=new DibujarBrujula(this);
        setContentView(brujula);


        x_a = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.azimut);

        try {

            DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

            mBrujula = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mBrujula, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.sensor.getType() == mAccelerometer.getType()) {
            float x = event.values[0];
            float y = event.values[1];
            float z = event.values[2];
            enviarDatosAcelerometro(x, y, z, azimut);
        } else if (event.sensor.getType() == mBrujula.getType()) {
            this.azimut = event.values[0];
            x_a.setText("x = " + Float.toString(event.values[0]));//para probar que se ven los valores del los sensores
        }
    }

    public void enviarDatosAcelerometro(float x, float y, float z, float azimut2) {
        String info = "x=" + x + " y=" + y + " z=" + z + " grados=" + azimut2;
        new EnviarDatos(info).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }


    private class EnviarDatos extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        private String info;

        public EnviarDatos(String info) {
            this.info = info;
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            try {
                byte[] bytesInfo = info.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(bytesInfo, bytesInfo.length, IPAddress, puertoServ);
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        }
    }

}
```

Y quiero pasar el parmetro azimut a la clase DibujarBrujula, para poder utilizar el valor de ese sensor

```
public class DibujarBrujula extends View {

private float direction;
private Bitmap bitmapAguja, bitmapVelocidad;
private double gradosVel, gradosVelActual;
public Matrix matrixAguja, matrixBrujula;

public DibujarBrujula(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    int height = this.getHeight();
    int width = this.getWidth();
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    if (bitmapAguja == null)
        bitmapAguja = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aguja);
    if (bitmapVelocidad == null) {
        bitmapVelocidad = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.esfera);
        bitmapVelocidad = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapVelocidad, width, width, false);
    }
    matrixAguja = new Matrix();
    matrixAguja.setTranslate(width / 2 - bitmapAguja.getWidth() / 2, height /2 - bitmapAguja.getHeight()+600 );
    matrixAguja.postRotate(-direction , width / 2, height / 2);
    matrixBrujula = new Matrix();
    matrixBrujula.postTranslate(width / 2 - bitmapVelocidad.getWidth() / 2, height / 2 - bitmapVelocidad.getWidth() / 2);
    double difGradosVel = gradosVel - gradosVelActual;
    if (difGradosVel != 0 && Math.abs(difGradosVel) > 1) {
        if (difGradosVel > 0)
            gradosVelActual++;
        else
            gradosVelActual--;
        matrixBrujula.postRotate((float) (-gradosVelActual ), width / 2, height / 2);
    } else {
        matrixBrujula.postRotate((float) (-gradosVel ), width / 2, height / 2);
    }

    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapAguja, matrixAguja, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapVelocidad, matrixBrujula, null);
}

public void setDirection(float direction) {
    this.direction = direction;
    this.invalidate();
}

public void setValorFinalVel(double vel) {
    double maxValorVel = 6.0;
    gradosVel = vel * 360.0 / maxValorVel;
}
```

}

Es decir, quiero que el valor 'azimut' del MainActivity se "pase" al valor 'direction' de la clase DibujarBrujula, para trabajar con él

he probado a crear un get en el MainActivity:

```
        public float getAzimut(){
        return azimut;
    }
```

y utilizarlo en el constructor:

```
    public DibujarBrujula(Context context, float direction) {
    super(context);
    this.direction=MainActivity.getAzimut();
}
```

Pero me sale el siguiento texto: non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

---

he probado a crear un get en el MainActivity:

```
        public float getAzimut(){
        return azimut;
    }
```

y utilizarlo en el constructor:

```
    public DibujarBrujula(Context context, float direction) {
    super(context);
    this.direction=MainActivity.getAzimut();
}
```

Pero me sale el siguiento texto: non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Si desde MainActivity quieres pasar un objeto con ciertas propiedades completadas al abrir la actividad DibujarBrujula lo puedes hacer a través del constructor

Comment: Pablo abajo dejo el código, que creo que te refieres a eso, pero aún así sigue sin funcionar

Comment: En vez de hacer una respuesta edita la que ya has hecho. No puedes hacerlo así ya que para eso debería ser estático. Al crear el objeto le pasas azimut al constructor y lo recoges igual que haces con el contexto, sin crear un método.

Comment: No te entiendo Pablo, el contexto lo recojo porque extiendo de la clase View pero el azimut no está definido en la clase View, si pudieses pasarme la forma de la que tú la haría te lo agradecería bastante

Comment: Puedes poner el código donde creas la actividad DibujarBrujula? así te podré poner una respuesta para que lo veas claro

Comment: Acabo de editar con todo el código de la Actividad y la clase DibujarBrujula

Comment: He formulado una respuesta, por favor, borra la que has puesto abajo en vez de editar la pregunta para que quede todo claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo un par de cosas algo raras.

Primero, no se porqué heredas DibujarBrujula de View y tampoco se porqué haces setContentView(brujula). Para pasarle azimut viendo como tienes el código, la manera más sencilla es crear un método setAzimut pero en la clase DibujarBrujula.

```
public class DibujarBrujula extends View {

    private float direction;
    private Bitmap bitmapAguja, bitmapVelocidad;
    private double gradosVel, gradosVelActual;
    public Matrix matrixAguja, matrixBrujula;

    public DibujarBrujula(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public setAzimut (float aux){
        this.direccion = aux;
    }

    //No pongo el resto de código de la clase porque es el mismo
```

Ahora, desde el Main cuando quieras rellenar este parámetro sólo tendrás que llamar al método a través del objeto brujula que ya tienes:

```
brujula.setAzimut(1.234586);  //Le pasas el valor que te haga falta
```

Lo pongo así porque veo que creas tu objeto brujula al principio del programa. La otra opción sería crearlo una vez que tengas ya el dato azimut, con lo cual le podrías pasar el parámetro a través del constructor.

Para esto, tendrías que añadir este parámetro al constructor de la clase DibujarBrujula, sería así:

```
public class DibujarBrujula extends View {

    private float direction;
    private Bitmap bitmapAguja, bitmapVelocidad;
    private double gradosVel, gradosVelActual;
    public Matrix matrixAguja, matrixBrujula;

    public DibujarBrujula(Context context, float aux) {
        super(context);
        direccion = aux;
    }
```

y a la hora de crearlo desde el Main sería así:

```
brujula=new DibujarBrujula(this, valor); //Siendo valor el azimut que lo quieres pasar
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Pablo, está perfecto, ando muy perdido todavía con Android Studio...

Comment: ánimo, si alguna vez te hace falta ayuda ya sabes, formulando una buena pregunta se te podrá ayudar en lo que haga falta.